# Pulsing is not happening for the `marker` added using react-leaflet open street map

Tags: reactjs, react-leaflet

Pulsing is not happening for the `marker` added using react-leaflet open street map. Could someone please advise how can I fix this issue ?

```
import React from 'react';
import L from 'leaflet';
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from 'react-leaflet';
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css'; 

const MapComponent = () => {
  const [lat, setLat] = React.useState(-27.4697);
  const [lng, setLng] = React.useState(153.0251);
  const [zoom, setZoom] = React.useState(12);

  const markerImage1 = "images/logo1.png";

  const customIcon = new L.Icon({
    iconUrl: '/images/marker.png',
    iconSize: [55, 55],
    iconAnchor: [2, 12],
    popupAnchor: [1, -34],
    tooltipAnchor: [16, -28],
  });

  return (

    <div className="flex-wrap">
      <div className="h-48 md:h-[600px] w-full">
        <MapContainer center={[lat, lng]} zoom={zoom} style={{ height: '100%', zIndex: 0 }}>
          <TileLayer
            url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
            attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          />
          <Marker className="pulse" position={[lat, lng]} icon={customIcon}>
            <Popup>

              <div className="w-[200px] flex flex-col bg-sky-100 p-2 rounded items-center">
                <img src={markerImage1} alt="Marker" className="self-center rounded-full w-14 h-14 mr-2 mb-2" />
                <div>
                  <h3 className="self-center text-base font-montserrat font-bold whitespace-nowrap dark:text-white text-stone-400"> Test marker <br /> Australia </h3>
                </div>
              </div>
            </Popup>
          </Marker>
        </MapContainer>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MapComponent;
```

index.css:

```
@keyframes pulse {
  0%, 100% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }

  50% {
    transform: scale(1.2);
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
}

.pulse {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  animation: pulse 2s infinite;
}
```